# Python cannot see module

Tags: python

Hello guys i have this directory

```
C:\Python27
--C:\Python27\pysec-master
----C:\Python27\pysec-master\pysec
     __init__.py
     example.py
     models.py
     xbrl.py
     xbrl_fundamentals.py
```

I am trying to run this command

```
from pysec import xbrl
```

and i am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    from pysec import xbrl
ImportError: No module named pysec
```

How is this possible? This code was written by a [professional](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec) and you can clearly see the file named pysec

Comment: You should read about [module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) first.

Comment: Is `C:\Python27\pysec-master` in `sys.path` ? Nope? Add it to `sys.path` as `sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27\pysec-master')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered by [mskimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553095/mskimm) in the comments sections and runs as:

Is `C:\Python27\pysec-master` in `sys.path` ? Nope? Add it to `sys.path` as `sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27\pysec-master')`